# Reading excel file fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch, textdecoder

I am trying to read a excel file and create one locally. I have the below code

```
(async function () {
  const fetchPromise = fetch(url);
  let stream = await fetchPromise;
  let reader = stream.body.getReader();
  let decoder = new TextDecoder();
  while(true) {
    const {done, value} = await reader.read();
    if (done){
      break;
    }
    let res = decoder.decode(value, {stream: true, ignoreBOM: false});
    console.log(res);
  }
})();
```

I am seeing garbled characters when printing value of variable `res`.

when i execute `file -I` on the source file i am trying to read + create locally i see

```
count-3.xlsx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=binary
```

What encoding scheme should i be passing to `TextDecoder` so i do not see garbled characters?

Comment: Have you tried writing it to an actual file and seeing if it opens in excel? Because if you open a normal .xlsx file in a text editor, you will see 'garbled characters' or some form of binary code or hex bytes or something, it won't look like readable text

Comment: @TKoL, yes i tried to write, but when i open the file i appears corrupt.